# Type Error: 1 is undefined in jQuery.DataTables.min.js

Tags: codeigniter, datatables-1.10

I am using DataTables with CodeIgniter following [this tutorial](http://www.ahmed-samy.com/php-codeigniter-full-featrued-jquery-datatables-part-1/).

While I am loading my view, I am getting error in console as:

```
Type Error: 1 is undefined in jquery.dataTables.min.js 49:323
```

My Controller code is:

```
    public function index()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
        $this->load->library('table');
        $tmpl = array('table_open' => '<table id="doc_table"">');
        $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
        $this->table->set_heading('TMT_PK_Key', 'Name');
        $this->load->view('doctor');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('home');
    }
}

function getDocData()
{
    $this->load->library('Datatables');
    $this->datatables
        ->select('TMT_PK_Key, Name')
        ->from('Doctor_Basic');
        //->join('Doctor_Email', 'Doctor_Basic.TMT_PK_key = Doctor_Email.TMT_PK_key')
        //->select('Email')
        //->join('Doctor_Mobile', 'Doctor_Basic.TMT_PK_key = Doctor_Mobile.TMT_PK_key')
        //->select('Mobile');

    echo $this->datatables->generate();
}
}
```

My views code(some code is omitted like js call):

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php echo $this->table->generate(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var oTable = jQuery('#doc_table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '/ci/doctor/getDocData',
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayStart ": 100,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='/ci/images/loading.gif'>"
        },
        'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        jQuery.ajax
        ({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POSt',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': aoData,
            'success': fnCallback
        });
    },
});
```

});

Data returned (inspect element=>Network=>Response):

```
draw:0
recordsTotal:1331
recordsFiltered:1331
data:Array
   0:Object
   TMT_PK_Key:"TMTPK"
   Name:"ABC"
```

I tried looking in forums but couldn't find the solution.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by updating the DataTables to 1.10.5 from the [Here](http://www.datatables.net/download/)